# Kafka Connect in distributed mode on Kubernetes received unknown topic or partition error in fetch for partition

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm trying to deploy Debezium source connector on Kafka Connect 3.1.0 in distributed mode. I deployed 3 Kafka brokers with 3 Zookeeper instances and built Kafka Connect pod from Debezium tutorial.  I dived into Kafka Connect pod logs and encountered those warnings:

```bash
2022-09-09 12:23:22,392 WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-connect-cluster-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Received unknown topic or partition error in fetch for partition connect-cluster-offsets-10 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher) [KafkaBasedLog Work Thread - connect-cluster-offsets]
```

while logs from running *connect-distributed.sh* show this:

```bash
[2022-09-09 12:39:29,570] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Rebalance started (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.WorkerCoordinator:222)
[2022-09-09 12:39:29,570] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] (Re-)joining group (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.WorkerCoordinator:535)
[2022-09-09 12:39:29,571] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Successfully joined group with generation Generation{generationId=13803870, memberId='connect-1-fb18f92c-6c73-461b-8b42-4bdee3e91e99', protocol='sessioned'} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.WorkerCoordinator:595)
[2022-09-09 12:39:29,575] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Successfully synced group in generation Generation{generationId=13803870, memberId='connect-1-fb18f92c-6c73-461b-8b42-4bdee3e91e99', protocol='sessioned'} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.WorkerCoordinator:761)
[2022-09-09 12:39:29,575] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Joined group at generation 13803870 with protocol version 2 and got assignment: Assignment{error=0, leader='connect-1-91c7dc97-e954-4b7e-b3a3-25021ba65dc3', leaderUrl='http://10.244.234.90:8083/', offset=1, connectorIds=[], taskIds=[], revokedConnectorIds=[], revokedTaskIds=[], delay=0} with rebalance delay: 0 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1853)
[2022-09-09 12:39:29,575] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Starting connectors and tasks using config offset 1 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1378)
[2022-09-09 12:39:29,575] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Finished starting connectors and tasks (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1406)
```

I' ve changed *connect-distributed.properties* multiple times, as well as modifying curl command to deploy a connector. I especially experimented with *listeners* and *advertised.listeners* fields by changing service names, ports, protocols. So far, the connect-distributed.properties file looks like this (meaning *connect-distributed.sh* doesn't crash):

```bash
bootstrap.servers=kafka-whatever-kafka-bootstrap:9092
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
offset.storage.topic=connect-cluster-offsets
offset.storage.replication.factor=1
config.storage.topic=connect-cluster-configs
config.storage.replication.factor=1
status.storage.topic=connect-cluster-status
status.storage.replication.factor=1
plugin.path=/opt/kafka/plugins
listeners=http://0.0.0.0:9092,http://0.0.0.0:9090,http://0.0.0.0:9091,http://0.0.0.0:9093
advertised.listeners=http://connect-cluster-connect-api:8083
group.id=connect-cluster
```

curl command to deploy a connector that I used is:

```bash
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://127.0.0.1:8080/connectors/ -d '{ "name": "inventory-connector", "config": { "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector", "tasks.max": "1", "database.hostname": "mysql", "database.port": "3306", "database.user": "debezium", "database.password": "dbz", "database.server.id": "184054", "database.server.name": "dbserver1", "database.include.list": "inventory", "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka-whatever-kafka-bootstrap:9092", "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.inventory" } }'
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?  I'm running into something similar.

Comment: @NapoleonIkeJones I decided not to use Debezium